# How do I print a HTML page dynamicly generated with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, printing

I have a dynamicly generated document built using tables, with jquery. The data comes in a json file and it shapes  heights everywhere, picture colors, etc.
I won't post the entire code because it's massive, but here is a picture: [image: MyDoc]

Whenever I try to print that, the output is this: [image: MyDocPrinted]

As you can see, the canvas is fine but elements like the images and their background-color doesn't show up. The ruler on the left too, that is a background-repeat-y image that doesn't show up as well. (the bottom part is fine, I just didn't include it on the picture)

Here is my doc before the json data: [image: empty_doc]

Why the browser doesn't print what's on the screen correclty? I've tried media print but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you confirm that there's no hidden CSS property anywhere that is influencing the way CSS is applied when printing? Since it almost seems as if there's a global override on the 
_background_ property.

Comment: Check the print settings in your browser. Chrome, for example, has a checkbox to include or exclude background graphics.

Comment: `elements like the images and their background-color doesn't show up` this is normally a setting on the print screen. You can't control that via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @rob-moll and @rory-mccrossan suggested, make sure your 'print' screen preview allows for images to be displayed. On Chromium this option van be found on the print screen (Ctrl+P) under "More Settings" and is called "Background graphics".

On Firefox, this setting can be found under "Page Setup..." in the tab titled 'Format & Options', there you'll find a section named 'Options' that includes a checkbox to enable 'Print Background (colors & images).

Then, make sure there's no (hidden) CSS-statement anywhere along the lines of:

```
@media print {
  * {background:none}
}
```

Or anything that would influence the elements that you're trying to print.

Comment: That was it. I tried everything but checking that background graphics checkbox! Thank you so much! Should've figured that it was something simple because there isn't many questions for that problem...

Comment: On your last sentence: That's a common experience. I too often find myself questioning whether or not I've overlooked a simple solution when it's hard to find an answer. So don't take it too hard on yourself, it happens to the best! This just shows that it's helpful to the community to regularly visit stackoverflow and check/answer recent questions, like I did with yours.